# Upload progress between Activities

Tags: android, rx-java

Here is what I have:

`Activity A`

`Activity B`

`Fragment B1`

`Activity A` launches `Activity B` which starts `Fragment B1` where I start a `Observable` to upload a file.  After the upload is started `Activity B` will finish.  I need to be able somehow let `Activity A` that the upload started and when it finishes.

What I've tried is using a `LocalBroadcastManager` which works but I was wondering if there is another or better way to do this?

For letting `Activity A` know that a upload starts I've used `startActivityforResult` but that only let's me know when the upload starts.

Comment: you can use a ResultReceiver or ContentResolver. registerContentObserver/notifyChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution can be to use the pattern Observer/Observable. Every activity is a observer of upload event, while the uploader component of your app is the observable. When Activity starts (using onStart() callback of Activity*), it registers as observer to uploader component; when Activity stops ( using onStop() callback of Activity*), it is removed. 
Uploader component notifies all events (Start download, end download, etc.) just to register observers.

*Alternative way it's using [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) in Application class of your app.